# Get HWND for Direct3D init

Tags: c++

I am pretty new into C++ and I am following tutorial "Getting started with Direct3D" from [directxtutorial.com](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-4-1)

I have used Niko Kauppi's Vulkan tutorials ['youtube link'](https://youtu.be/J87M6HdcjS0) to create window, but I am not using Vulkan here. Current project has win32 window and glfw window.

DXTutorial has this void function: `void initD3D(HWND hWnd) {}` 
I'd like to know how to get the handle to the current window I am using ( either win32 or glfw ).

The win32 window is like this: `http://pastebin.com/P54cX6gr`

and glfw window is like this: `http://pastebin.com/HD0Yxk2S`

I ran out of links.

Comment: First of all, why are you using a glfw (openGL loader) window for directX?

Comment: "either win32 or glfw", I can currently create those 2 types of windows. I have GLFW for future renderer's I may add (OpenGL, Vulkan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Windows window handle from a GLFW window with [`glfwGetWin32Window`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html#gafe5079aa79038b0079fc09d5f0a8e667).

If you want to use WinAPI directly then, when you register the [`WindowProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) for the window, the first parameter passed to it is the window handle. You can then use `WM_CREATE` event to handle the initialization.

Comment: So if I add    'case WM_CREATE' how do I get the handle there over to renderer? Renderer has its own class. As does windows.

Comment: @Pineapple you need to make the reference available there somehow. Either from outers scope or with `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);`, storing a pointer to that renderer in the userdata beforehand.

Comment: At line 15 of window_win32.cpp, there is `GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));`, and at line 88 `SetWindowLongPtr(_win32_window, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this);` The Renderer header file looks like this [link](http://pastebin.com/Q1JCVkbc) and cpp file [link](http://pastebin.com/BGPQ6UtY)

Comment: @Pineapple don't get me wrong; I am fine with helping you, but I won't write your code for you.

Comment: I don't mean that, I just don't get how to get the window handle to renderer, so I thought giving link to the code would help explaining. I am now adding OpenGL renderer ( I know GL better because I have messed with it in C# before ), maybe that helps me figure it out.

Comment: I created a function in Window class that returns GLFWwindow* it works nicely ( able to render in OpenGL ), now to create something similar to the win32 window.

Comment: Okkay, here is a little problem. With GLFW + OpenGL, the OpenGL renderer needed the GLFW window only in render_frame function. With the DirectX9 renderer, it needs the window handle for initialization ( initialization happens right after the Renderer is created, window is created afterwards ), which means the handle will be null and initialization fails.

Comment: @Pineapple If you need the window handle then the only way is to initialize the renderer after the window has been created.

Comment: Yeah. I'll make init function public and remove it from constructor.